# ASP.NET User.IsInRole clarification

Tags: asp.net

I need to implement authorisation based on Active Directory group. Could someone please clarify how the code below works?

```
User.IsInRole("Human Resouces")
```

Question:

> 1. Is role "Human Resources" checked against Active directory group?
> 2. If not, how do I enable so that isInRole actually checks the Member
>      Group in Active directory.
> 3. Or does it check against role on IIS Server machine?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to use `Forms Authentication` and then use `Active directory group`?

Comment: Hi Thomas, it's intranet application with Windows Auth. do i need to hock up to AD or IIS already does that to get group to which user belongs in AD

Answer (score 0):

This requires some setup, check out these following resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

If you follow the approach of defining a principal that sets the principal to the User property, you can use User.IsInRole to check the AD authorization store.  The User (an IPrincipal) represents the information from the authentication mode setting (either forms or windows); AD is typically setup through forms authentication.

HTH.

Comment: basically my question is. If we use windows authentcation and isinRole does it checks the role in AD or Widows Server where IIS is installed?

Comment: It checks the windows security permissions where IIS is installed on, essentially the network the server is on... for instance, if running an intranet application, and all users are on the same domain, I could access their windows domain account info (user name, auth type, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this MSDN post it explain the things as your requirements are.
[How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)